# Python output gives bytes instead of string when extracting data between 2 keywords

Tags: python, regex

A have the following code:

```
import re
import csv
import time

print(time.ctime())

input_name = r"C:\Users\npatel\Documents\Coremotion 
Data\MotionData\data_file.csv"
output_name = r"C:\Users\npatel\Documents\Coremotion 
Data\MotionData\output_file.csv"

with open(input_name, 'r') as f_input, open(output_name, 'w') as f_output:
# Read whole file in
all_input = f_input.read()  

# Extract interesting lines
ab_input = re.findall(r'start(.*?)stop', all_input, re.DOTALL)[0]

csv_input = csv.reader(ab_input)
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)


for input_row in csv_input:
    # Skip any empty rows
    if input_row:
        # Write row at a time to the output
        csv_output.writerows(input_row)

        print(input_row)
```

I am trying to extract data between start and stop but it extracts single bytes. It separates all letters and numbers from a whole word or a float number. The output is:

```
 Tue Nov 21 10:35:33 2017
  ['2']
  ['0']
  ['1']
  ['7']
  ['-']
  ['1']
  ['1']
  ['-']
  ['1']
  ['3']

  ['', '']
  ['m']
  ['o']
  ['t']
  ['i']
```

Comment: are you on py3 or py2? also, kind of hard to help without example of what the regex is supposed to parse.

Comment: py3 , itt parses a CSV file that has sensor data on it like accelerometerx,y,x and other values. @ahed87

Comment: using 'rt' instead of 'r' probably helps with the bytes (same for 'w') if you want strings, without the actual extract from the file to parse there is no way of helping with the regex, although do you really need regex, in a lot of cases the built in string functions will do the job just fine (and is often a bit more predictable at least for me)

Comment: Can you help me with the code of string functions? I am new to python so am not aware of it this code in the question I got it from stackoverflow as well. Also I tried with rt but didn't do the job. @ahed87

Comment: well, the rt will only do what you mentioned in the title, read the file as text and not bytes, but that is not your issue, since that did not throw an error. you have another problem. without some content of what you are putting into the csv.reader it's not possible to help as such, only give some hints.

Comment: The csv file consists of various rows and columns with float and string.I want to extract the rows and columns between the keywords start and stop. If that helps? @ahed87

Comment: if you pass a string to the csv.writer, it will put that in a single column (not row), but your output (which you have not said if it's from the print or the output.csv) has the square brackets from a list, so nothing here makes sense. My guess is that you don't have what you think from the csv.reader. Try some print statements in different places to be sure of what you actually have in your variables. For string handling, it's best to google some tutorials, not hard for example '1,2,3'.split(',') gives a list like ['1','2','3']

Comment: well, the only thing that really would enable any one of us to help is actually that you post part of the file that you try to parse, without it it's just a guessing game for anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader is not the right tool for the job.

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its **next**() method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable.

So in your case it iterates over the string.

Try replacing `csv_input = csv.reader(ab_input)` with something simpler like `csv_input = ab_input.split(',')`. That will give you a list of values on that CSV line.

Comment: Hey when I do this the output comes normally but when i open the file it is not changed, can you help me here?

Comment: You're likely feeding a string into `csv.writer`. It then iterates through the string using the 'next()' method and this gives you one letter at the time. You need to either feed the `csv_input` list to the `csv.writer` or write your content to the file differently.